# Is it possible to load another php file in a pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am try to create a system where the user would click on a link and that link would be loaded in a pop-up on the same page. For example; you have a php link like

`<a href='user_message.php?hash=$hash'>$username</a>`

is it possible that if the user clicks on that link, it would load in a pop-up on the same page. Please any help would be appreciated.

I have within my skills 
**PHP**

```
echo"<a href='account.php?hash=$hash>connect</a>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $('a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.boxes').fadeIn('slow').load('user_connect.php?hash=$hash');
});
</script>
```

I believe that the fact that i have `prevntDefault` on `a` won't make this work.
Please how is this possible

Comment: You might want to consider a javascript plug-in such as [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: You can create a div which is hidden by CSS and after click the link, you can make it visible using very sample jQuery !

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but it should be fairly easy:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
   e.preventDeafult(); //don't let browser follow the link

   var href = $(this).attr('href'); //get the href from original link
   var options = "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500";
  //Now open the popup
  window.open(href, 'NameOfTheWindow', options);
})
```

Remember, this code will override behaivior of ALL links on you page. If you need only some of them be opened in popup, add class and use it in handler.

```
     $(document).on('click', 'a.js-open-in-popup', func...
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
.pop {
 display: none;
}
```

html :

```
<div id="pop" class="pop ">ur data</div>
<a href="" id="link"></a>
```

js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#link").click.(function(){
  jQuery("#pop").css("display", "block");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the code in my question actually worked. Noticed I had solved the question trying to explain the issue here

Since i `echoed` the `JavaScript` in `PHP` the `$hash` was accessible to the `JS` (cause of initial problem was that i wrote `JS script` outside the `PHP` code. The `.load` effectively works.

**style for** `.boxes`

```
.boxes {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9000;
    display: none;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
}
```

Thank you all for contribution.